# three.js How to scale object/mesh without change of thickness of sides

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Is there a way to scale imported object (from stl file) without changing the thickness of sides of object - I import furniture model and I would like to scale it, but scale method in Three.js scale the whole object.

Is there another way to do it than load each side (front, back, left, right, bottom and top) and scale them independently (and of course translate them accordingly)?

[There is an example - cupboard before and after scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffbz9.png)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you're seeing versus what you're expecting?

Comment: `Geometry.scale(x,y,z)`, how much you want to scale along three axes. also, you can set value to mesh.scale like `mesh.scale.x = 2 ; mesh.scale.y = 1;`.

Comment: If I use `mesh.scale.x` the whole mesh will be scaled (including thickness of sides).